# How to keep assembly files with --save-temps when multiple targets use the same source file?

Tags: c++, assembly, cmake, g++

If I compile the C++ program */tmp/src/main.cc*

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {

#ifdef demo1
  std::cout << "Output from demo1\n";
#endif

#ifdef demo2
  std::cout << "Output from demo2\n";
#endif

}
```

with the build instructions from the file */tmp/src/CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(test_save_temps LANGUAGES CXX)

function(my_add_executable name)
  add_executable(${name})
  target_sources(${name} PRIVATE main.cc)

  # target_compile_options(${name} PRIVATE --save-temps)

  target_compile_definitions(${name} PRIVATE
    ${name}
  )
endfunction()

my_add_executable(demo1)
my_add_executable(demo2)
```

everything looks OK.

```
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp$ mkdir /tmp/build
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp$ cd /tmp/build
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build$ cmake -G Ninja /tmp/src
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.2.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/build
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build$ ninja
[4/4] Linking CXX executable demo1
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build$ ls
build.ninja  CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  cmake_install.cmake  demo1  demo2  rules.ninja
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build$ ./demo1
Output from demo1
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build$ ./demo2
Output from demo2
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build$
```

But if I remove the comment from the file */tmp/src/CMakeLists.txt*
to activate the line

```
 target_compile_options(${name} PRIVATE --save-temps)
```

and do the same

```
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp$ mkdir /tmp/build_with_save_temps
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp$ cd /tmp/build_with_save_temps
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build_with_save_temps$ cmake -G Ninja /tmp/src
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.2.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/build_with_save_temps
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build_with_save_temps$ ninja
[4/4] Linking CXX executable demo1
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build_with_save_temps$ ls
build.ninja  CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  cmake_install.cmake  demo1  demo2  main.ii  main.s  rules.ninja
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build_with_save_temps$ ./demo1
Output from demo1
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build_with_save_temps$ ./demo2
Output from demo1
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build_with_save_temps$ find . -name '*.s'
./main.s
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build_with_save_temps$
```

The output from the program **demo2** is not correct.

I was hoping to find two versions of the assembly file *main.s* in the build directory.

Here I provide some extra information about my computer system

- cmake 3.13.2
- g++ 8.2.0
- ninja 1.8.2
- Ubuntu 18.10

How can I modify */tmp/src/CMakeLists.txt* to keep both versions of the assembly file *main.s*?

### **Update with solution**:

Everything started to work when I use `-save-temps=obj` as suggested in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53811064/757777 by the user **fritzone**.

I replaced

```
target_compile_options(${name} PRIVATE --save-temps)
```

with

```
target_compile_options(${name} PRIVATE -save-temps=obj)
```

Now I get both assembly files

```
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build2$ find . -name '*.s'
./CMakeFiles/demo2.dir/main.cc.s
./CMakeFiles/demo1.dir/main.cc.s
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build2$
```

and the executables **demo1** and **demo2** works as expected

```
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build2$ ./demo1
Output from demo1
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build2$ ./demo2
Output from demo2
ubuntu@laptop:/tmp/build2$
```

Comment: I would try to make the assembly output name dependent of target config. I believe this should be possible with CMake although I've no ready receipt at hand. (In our case, we suffix libraries and executables for debug with `-d` for "historical" reasons although it's actually not necessary due to separated build output dirs.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to specify for the compiler the `-save-temps=obj` option, in order to save the temporary files based on the object files, according to: 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#Developer-Options

So, you will need to modify your cmake file to look like:

```
target_compile_options(${name} PRIVATE -save-temps=obj)
```

(or similar) in order to save the temporary files depending on the name of the application you try to compile.